# Show or Present ViewController?

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have an app in swift that starts with a rootViewController containing 3 buttons.

The first one should open a tabViewController with 3 tabs in it.

The second one should open a navViewController with a nested TableViewController that opens another tableViewController

The last one should open a regular view controller with 2 buttons, both opening a navController with a nested tableViewController

Which is the best "pattern" to use? should I use a ContainerViewController as root?

Which method is best to use for the main 3 buttons of the rootViewController to open the related controllers, the show or the present?

This is a sketch of my app: http://i60.tinypic.com/6jq537.png

Answer (score 0):

The main thing to ask is how are these separate views related? And how are they related to the "menu" view at the beginning?

1. Tab View -
2. Nested Table View -
3. Another menu to two more tables...

First I'll go through how I would build each individually...

**Tab View**

I would probably create this in its own Storyboard. You don't specify if the tabs will have their own navigation in them? If so then each tab should start with a NavigationController. i.e. 1 tab bar controller with 3 tabs. 3 navigation controllers (one per tab) and then the root view controller of each navigation controller will be the content of the tab.

**Nested Table View**

The navigation of this should be handled in a navigation controller. So you either want to present a navigation controller with the first table view controller in it or you want to use a navigation controller to present it in the first place.

**Third view**

This is essentially a duplication of the menu view. Except each button goes to the **Nested Table View** mentioned above. Again, you will need a navigation controller.

**What I would do**

You probably should be starting with a Navigation Controller as your root view. If you want to get back to your menu view easily then that would make sense.

Then the issue of button 2 and 3 are trivial as you just push them onto the navigation controller.

For the tab bar controller I'd also push it onto the navigation controller but maybe think about hiding the navigation bar during the transition so as not to get caught up in which navigation controller is doing what.